# How would I install Wordpress on network solutions without interrupting the current site?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, file-structure

I am re-designing a website that already exists on network solutions. I would like to keep the same domain for the new site but I am going to use wordpress through network solutions.

How would I install Wordpress without interrupting the current site?

Then once the new website is done, I would need to replace it with the existing site without interrupting the file structure to keep all images and links I've coded into the "staging" instance?

Answer (score 0):

What people usually do in this case is create a subdomain where the development version of the site will live (eg. `https://staging.example.com` or `https://dev.example.com`) so both sites can coexist without affecting one another.

Another approach would be to create a folder in the main domain (eg. `https://www.example.com/staging/` or `https://www.example.com/dev/`) and do all the work there. Personally I don't use this approach, I prefer the one mentioned above the best as it keeps both sites completely separated.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look into creating a subdomain.

Comment: Don't mention it, @JulieKaySeely. If my answer helped, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).